# C# ftp file upload not working

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

I am using this code that I got from MSDN:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://a.b.com/home/grad/G140315METST-HT001.jpg");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("G140315METST-HT001.jpg");
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();
```

But I am getting this error:

**The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.**

On this line `Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();`

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried uploading the same file with a common FTP client? Maybe the server really does not allow this filename...

Comment: Yes I used filezila and it worked.

Comment: is the path valid? i mean home and grad folders exist on the server

Comment: @manishDalal> Yes, it exist.

Comment: when you connect using FileZilla, which folder does it opens?

Comment: i think using // after a.b.com will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to show full local path in StreamReader.
Try this

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("D:\\G140315METST-HT001.jpg");
```

Put your file in disk D:

Comment: That s not the problem. it search in bin folder for the image.